# AngularJS : get back data from a json array with an id

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json file where i am stocking informations from all the people in my database. I actually use it to display first name, last name in a web page and i want to add the possibility to display the details of every person.

To do so i'm using the id of the person like this :

```
.when('/people/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/people-detail.html'})
```

It works pretty well, i have a page generated for every person, which is nice. But now I would like to get the information of the person back.

The easiest way would have been to have a json file for every person, but i don't particularly like the idea of having so much file. 
So my actual idea is to iterate through the people.json file to find the good one and using it but it's not working.

Here's my controller :

```
var PeopleController = angular.module ('PeopleController', []);

PeopleController.controller('PeopleDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $scope.search = function() {
            var url = 'data/people.json';
            $http.get(url).success(httpSuccess).error(function() {
                alert('Unable to get back informations :( ');
            });
        }
        httpSuccess = function(response) {
            $scope.persons = response;
        }

        function getById(arr, id) {
            for (var d = 0, len = arr.length; d < len; d += 1) {
                if (arr[d].id === id) {
                    return arr[d];  
                }
            }
        }
        $scope.search();
        $scope.person = getById($scope.persons,$routeParams.id);
    }]);
```

Well, maybe my solution is bad since it doesn't work, but i didn't find another way to do so.

Now i'm all yours :)

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `$scope.search` method contains `$http.get()` which is asynchronous.

What that means is your next line (the one that sets `$scope.person`) executes **before** the json file has been read. As such, `$scope.persons` is empty at the time it is executed.

You can take advantage of the fact that `$http.get()` returns a chainable [promise](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) here.

So if you change your `search()` function to return that promise, you can then use `then()` to populate `person` when everything has been successful:

```
$scope.search = function() {
  var url = 'data/people.json';

  return $http.get(url).success(httpSuccess).error(function() {
    alert('Unable to get back informations :( ');
  });

}
```

(note the `return` statement).

Then change the person population to take advantage of this:

```
$scope.search().then(function(){
  $scope.person = getById($scope.persons,$routeParams.id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works ! I don't know if it's the best solution (if i have to iterate 1000 times each time it's not really cool^^) but it still  works.
Well, i don't really understand the utility of the then() method. The only difference is that it waits for the promise. Even if you are not sure the success() will returns the promise, in this case you will have the error() method to manage this problem, right ?

Comment: If it works, then success returns a promise, yes. You should read up on promises if you want to understand more. It's a javascript principle which is well documented. Regarding your solution for getting by ID: the better option is to store your information in a database and not a json file, then to query that database directly by exposing an API on your server.

Comment: I will search for that, thank you. Using a database and a server was my first idea but the application is also supposed to work offline (mobile app with cordova) so i choose to stock everything locally and add the possibility to update the files by asking to the server.

Comment: For relatively small numbers, the iterations shouldn't be too much of a problem. I imagine cordova gives access to device databases though - might be worth looking into if the performance becomes an issue

Comment: It's still working. Solved my problem! But, just to check. Is there a better way to do it? It's been a long time since your answer. And since i'm starting learning angular now, is there a better way to get the element by it's id?

Comment: To be honest I haven't used cordova so I don't know, however the more efficient way is almost certainly to use a database. I would look at the cordova docs to find the best practice. All this said,  for 1000 items on a modern device, the load times probably won't be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I hope getting a person is a whole different event like on click. You can try grep:

```
$scope.person = function(_id) {
    return $.grep($scope.persons, function(item){
       return item.id == _id
    })[0];
}
```

Assuming you have all persons available otherwise this logic has to move inside the  part of the success callback for the http call.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i'm not using any jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I used ECMAScript 5 [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get person by id and moved your search by id  to success method since we are dealing with ajax call.

**Example:**

```
app.controller('PeopleDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
        $scope.search = function() {
            var url = 'data.json';
            $http.get(url).success(httpSuccess).error(function() {
                alert('Unable to get back informations :( ');
            });
        }
        httpSuccess = function(response) {
            $scope.persons = angular.fromJson(response);

            $scope.person = $scope.persons.filter(function(item){
             return item.id==routeParams.id //check for undefined; 
            });
        }


        $scope.search();

    }]);
```

Live Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/jPT6aC5UqLdHGJ1Clfkg?p=preview

Comment: I would argue it's better to keep the search by id separate, and return the promise, as with my answer. This makes it easy to use the same data retrieval function to perform other operations, or better, to migrate the data retrieval to a service.

Comment: filter creates an array.